# ES hostname in response

Tags: elasticsearch

I have few ES servers in load balancing mode. When I perform query to host1:9200 then one of host1,host2,host3 can process this query. Is it possible to get somehow this hostname in ES response?

In other words I'm looking for equivalent of "select myfield, @@servername FROM table" in MS SQL Server.

Thanks

Comment: try `host1:9200/_nodes`.

Comment: I'm rather looking for something like:

I perform query{}
and in response I have:

  {
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 3,
    "failed" : 0
  },

expected response would be:

{
  "took" : 12,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 3,
    "failed" : 0, 
    "hostname" : "MYFUNNYHOST3",
  },

Comment: Maybe I can use or implement some sort of plugin?

Comment: I think the main point is that elasticsearch is a distributed system and there's no single node that executes a search request, but more nodes are involved. Especially placing a host in the shards section doesn't make sense, as more nodes (one per shard at most) should fit in there. Maybe the search shards api would be interesting for you: http://elasticsearchserverbook.com/elasticsearch-0-90-search-shards-api/ . Also, it's important to understand the different phases of a search request: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/understanding-query-then-fetch-vs-dfs-query-then-fetch/ .

Comment: Thanks Javanna. I'm going to play with Search Shards API

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the http api you can get the hostname from the `Host` header in the response.

For example if you make your query with curl and you use the `-v` flag, it prints the response header where you can find the hostname that sends the response, in this case localhost:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test/_search" -v -d '
{
  "query": {"match_all":{}}
}'

* About to connect() to localhost port 9200 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 9200 (#0)
> GET /test/_search HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5
> Host: localhost:9200
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 32
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 875
<
```

In any case remember that if you have your data split in several shards, more than one host can be part of the process of the query.